# A question in knots

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Prove that if the orientation on one component of a two-component oriented link L is reversed then its linking number is negated. What is the linking number of the mirror-image link $\bar{L}$ ? Would either of these results still hold if L had three or more components?
Can you help me in that question.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Linking number is define between two components of a link.  So if there are components, you need to pick the two for which you are interested in their linking number.  And the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number#Properties_and_examples) has some of the info you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I saw.But I didn't find an example of a two component oriented link that I can use to prove the 1st question.And how can I prove that the linking number of the mirror image link is negate (Can i take an example of a mirror image knot and show that?).

Comment: You can look at the mirror image of individual crossings and how they change under mirror images.  But doing it for a specific link only shows that *that* link's linking number negates under mirror image.